# Approximating a non-linear relationship

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, nonlinear-functions

This is a scatter plot which illustrates the relationship between two variables:

[image]

It is obvious that this is a non-linear relationship. Both variables are time-series - the points are different observations.

How can I fit a curve (in python) that would approximate it?

EDIT:

Note that this is not a 2D relationship (as JamesPhilips pointed out below).

As I mentioned, these are two time series. I guess the correct thing to do would be to go for a 3D fit (including the time as a third dimension). So the function would take two inputs (x and time). How to do that?

EDIT2:

I'm attaching a sample of that dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q4zY7B-BwG8bmbQJT3QvRt6B2MD4k0a0)

EDIT3:

I am fortunate to have received two high quality answers by norok2 and JamesPhilips (many thanks to both of them!) and I will be exploring these. However, my impression is that none of the ideas proposed so far is making significant use of the fact that these are time series. My intuition is that there is some signal there (I know, not having the time stamps is making things complicated). So I will keep the question open for a while in case someone wants to chip in some other ideas.

Also, it seems that the dataset I put a link to was sorted not by using the original index (my bad!) - I am putting a link to the correctly sorted dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13TrRX1r-Mh58--4R2b6Dbg71cAE-1fXV/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: You most likely need to come up with your own model first. What kind of relationship should the two variables have? Then you can use data science packages to determine the best parameters for your model.

Comment: A function will normally yield a single output value for a single input value. The scatterplot appears to show that there are two "Y" values for most of the "X" values, so visually it appears that an ordinary "y = f(x)" type of equation will not model this data.

Comment: @JamesPhillips You are perfectly right. These are two time series so the relationship may not be direct.

Comment: Your comments indicate it is a `y = f(x)` function with `x` in `R` and `y` in `R²`. Unless you have a model which you can use to guess an analytical expression for which you can then fit its parameters, this is an excellent use case for regression with artificial neural networks.

Comment: I can provide graphical surface fitting Python code. Can you either post or link to the data? That way I can find an appropriate surface equation for the example.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thanks - that would be really helpful. I just added a link to the dataset.

Comment: The posted data has two columns. For fitting a surface equation of the form "z = f(x, y)" I would need x, y, and z - three columns.

Comment: @JamesPhillips These are consecutive measurements but the time stamp is missing. So I would rather use the index as the timestamp.

Comment: Done, see my answer. @norok2 I have provided an example 3D surface fitter, if you would please provide an example neural network fitter that would be most useful, because you state that this is an excellent use case for regression with artificial neural networks and such an example fitter would allow for direct comparison.

Comment: @JamesPhillips your model is for a function `y = f(x)` with `x` in `R²` and `y` in `R` which is the opposite of that OP indicated. Furthermore, you assume `f` to be of the form `a * x_0 + b * x_1 + c`. I'll see if i have time for producing an ANN-based example, given that the data is now available.

Comment: @Nick it may be more useful for you to plot the data in the csv as a function of the index. This will be closer to the physical model you are describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the question, the two columns `x` and `y` are two timeseries, i.e. `x(t)` and `y(t)`. The `t` parameter is represented by the index

First, let's load the data:

```
import io
import requests

import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib as mpl

import scipy.interpolate
import scipy.ndimage

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


file_id = '1q4zY7B-BwG8bmbQJT3QvRt6B2MD4k0a0'
url = requests.get('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + file_id)
csv_file = io.StringIO(url.text)
data = np.loadtxt(csv_file, delimiter=',')

x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
t = np.arange(len(x))
```

Now, `y(x)` may not, in general, be well defined. A more useful representation of the data is obtained by plotting `x(t)` and `y(t)` (perhaps along `y(x)`):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 4), squeeze=False)
ax[0, 0].scatter(t, x, color='k', s=8.0)
ax[0, 1].scatter(t, y, color='k', s=8.0)
ax[0, 2].scatter(x, y, color='k', s=8.0)

ax[0, 0].plot(t, x, color='b')
ax[0, 1].plot(t, y, color='b')
ax[0, 2].plot(x, y, color='b')
```

[image: vis]

Note that while the `y(x)` visualization gets two clustering, i.e. a stretched spiral and a straight line, without further information, this observation should not be over-interpreted.

---

Now, without a model to fit, what we could do is to have an interpolant numerical function for `x(t)` and `y(t)`.
If `x(t)` and `y(t)` are assumed to be noiseless, then a simple 1D interpolator, as provided by [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

```
func_x_t = sp.interpolate.interp1d(t, x, kind='cubic', assume_sorted=True)
func_y_t = sp.interpolate.interp1d(t, y, kind='cubic', assume_sorted=True)

x_interp = func_x_t(t)
y_interp = func_y_t(t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 4), squeeze=False)
ax[0, 0].scatter(t, x, color='k', s=8.0)
ax[0, 1].scatter(t, y, color='k', s=8.0)
ax[0, 2].scatter(x, y, color='k', s=8.0)

ax[0, 0].plot(t, x_interp, color='r')
ax[0, 1].plot(t, y_interp, color='r')
ax[0, 2].plot(x_interp, y_interp, color='r')
```

[image: interp]

Note that the red line is now *generated* by the interpolator. SciPy offers a variety of different interpolator which may be worth exploring.

---

If `x(t)` and `y(t)` are noisy measurements, a more useful interpolator may be obtained as above, but using a de-noised `x(t)` and `y(t)`. Here, I assume that the high-frequency oscillations observed are driven by noise (both in `x(t)` and in `y(t)`), and a simple but effective de-noising approach would be Gaussian filtering (as provided by [`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d.html):

```
smooth_x = sp.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d(x, 12.0, mode='nearest')
smooth_y = sp.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d(y, 12.0, mode='nearest')

func_x_t = sp.interpolate.interp1d(t, smooth_x, kind='cubic', assume_sorted=True)
func_y_t = sp.interpolate.interp1d(t, smooth_y, kind='cubic', assume_sorted=True)

x_smooth_interp = func_x_t(t)
y_smooth_interp = func_y_t(t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 4), squeeze=False)
ax[0, 0].scatter(t, x, color='k', s=8.0)
ax[0, 1].scatter(t, y, color='k', s=8.0)
ax[0, 2].scatter(x, y, color='k', s=8.0)

ax[0, 0].plot(t, smooth_x, color='g')
ax[0, 1].plot(t, smooth_y, color='g')
ax[0, 2].plot(smooth_x, smooth_y, color='g')

ax[0, 0].plot(t, x_smooth_interp, color='r')
ax[0, 1].plot(t, y_smooth_interp, color='r')
ax[0, 2].plot(x_smooth_interp, y_smooth_interp, color='r')
```

[image: smooth_interp]

Note that the `*_smooth` and `*_smooth_interp` gets plot on top of each other.

---

Another approach would be to use artificial neural network, e.g. from scikit-learn:

```
import sklearn as skl
import sklearn.neural_network as skl_nn
import sklearn.preprocessing

x_train = t.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = data

reg = skl_nn.MLPRegressor(
    solver='adam', hidden_layer_sizes=(24, 8), activation='tanh',
    learning_rate='adaptive', max_iter=1024)
reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_predict = reg.predict(x_train)

x_ann = y_predict[:, 0]
y_ann = y_predict[:, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 4), squeeze=False)
ax[0, 0].scatter(t, x, color='k', s=8.0)
ax[0, 1].scatter(t, y, color='k', s=8.0)
ax[0, 2].scatter(x, y, color='k', s=8.0)

ax[0, 0].plot(t, x, color='b')
ax[0, 1].plot(t, y, color='b')
ax[0, 2].plot(x, y, color='b')

ax[0, 0].plot(t, x_ann, color='r')
ax[0, 1].plot(t, y_ann, color='r')
ax[0, 2].plot(x_ann, y_ann, color='r')
```

[image: iterp_ann]

This gets you to an interpolator without the need to explicitly de-noise your target signal, which may be more or less desireable, depending on the application.

---

## Re-parametrized `x(t')` and `y(t')` with `t'(t)` (reordering)

If we relax the requirement that `x(t)` and `y(t)` are from a timeseries, we could investigate `x(t')` and `y(t')` for a given `t'(t)` transformation.

A possible transformation that results a somewhat interesting is obtained by sorting the CSV data by `y` (the timeseries are sorted by `x`):

```
data = data[data[:, 1].argsort()]
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
```

[image: vis_t']

with this transformation, we obtain the following interpolator for the ANN approach:

[image: ann_t']

and this for the smoothed `x(t')` and `y(t')`:

[image: interp_smooth_t']

Possibly, there are more effective reordering, but it may not be simple to formulate them.
A relatively simple formulation may involve clustering, but I believe this answer is already quite long.

(full code available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MVKTuEnqHHNWJgs80WpZ4w1l3r_0Ucbw))

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments, here is a graphical Python surface fitter reading data from the csv file. You should be able to mouse-click-drag and rotate the 3D ploys in 3-space for inspection.

In this example, I have guessed at a simple flat plane equation "csv_column_two = (a * index) + (b * csv_column_one) + c", because the 3D scatterplot and 3D surface plane shows what might be outliers on the left-hand side as plotted. With this example in hand you can easily try variations on data and equation. The fitter also prints the RMSE and R-squared value to aid in model evaluation and comparison.

[image: scatter plot]

[image: surface plot]

[image: contour plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('Index') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('CSV file column 1') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('CSV file column 2') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else there can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('Index') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('CSV file column 1') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else there can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('Index')
    axes.set_ylabel('CSV file column 1')
    axes.set_zlabel('CSV file column 2')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else there can be memory and process problems


def func(data, a, b, c):
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]
    return (a * x) + (b * y) + c


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = 'test_bfa_corr.csv'
    filetext = open(filename, 'rt').read()

    lines = filetext.split('\n')

    xData = []
    yData = []
    zData = []
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        spl = line.split(',')
        xData.append(i+1)
        yData.append(spl[0])
        zData.append(spl[1])

    xData = numpy.array(xData, dtype=float)
    yData = numpy.array(yData, dtype=float)
    zData = numpy.array(zData, dtype=float)

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] # these are the same as scipy default values in this example

    # here a non-linear surface fit is made with scipy's curve_fit()
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = initialParameters)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted parameters', fittedParameters)

    modelPredictions = func(data, *fittedParameters) 

    absError = modelPredictions - zData

    SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
    MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
    RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(zData))
    print('RMSE:', RMSE)
    print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```

Comment: This is great - thanks! Do you have any suggestion regarding a non-linear functional form? The original plot suggests some sort of non-linear relationship. Is there some systematic way to "guess" the functional form?

Comment: I used the 3D "function finder" on my zunzun.com open source Python curve and surface fitting web site, and did not find much better than a flat plane except for minute improvement when adding a y^2 term. The real problem at present in making  a better surface fit appears to be the presence of a relatively few data points above and below most of the other data (in my opinion).